# Failed to deserialize data for topic "testtopic" to Avro for sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, deserialization, apache-kafka-connect, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Here is the sink connector properties

```
 "name": "sink-testtopic-crdb",
 "config": {
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://roach-single:26257/sampledb?useSSL=false&reWriteBatchedInserts=true",
"topics": "testtopic",
"tasks.max": "1",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
"value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
"config.action.reload": "restart",
"errors.log.enable": "true",
"errors.log.include.messages": "true",
"print.key": "true",
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"connection.user": "root",
"connection.password": "",
"table.name.format": "schema_sample.sample_test",
"auto.create": true,
"auto.evolve": true,
"insert.mode": "insert",
"pk.mode": "none",
"pk.fields": "none",
"batch.size": 1,
"consumer.override.max.poll.records": 1}
```

Here is the schema registered in schema registry for "testtopic" by posting it to the url "http://localhost:8081/subjects/testtopic-value/versions"

```
{
    "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"sampleTest\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"testid\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"testname\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}", 
    "compatibility": "BACKWARD"}
```

Here is the message I'm inserting to Kafka Topic

```
{"testid": "226", "testname": "testSample21"}
```

Still messages are not getting ingested to ksql db and in the kafka connect logs, I could see the below error

'''
Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where consumed record is {topic='testtopic', partition=0, offset=16, timestamp=1691668835004, timestampType=CreateTime}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter:66)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic testtopic to Avro:
at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:148)

Comment: How exactly did you produce the data? Did you mistakenly use kafka-console-producer instead of the avro version? Have you verified that the console consumer can read your data?

Comment: yes I'm using the kafka-console-producer script to publish the message to the topic. May I know what is the avro version you are suggesting please ?

Comment: You must use [`kafka-avro-console-producer`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/cli-reference.html). Otherwise, you're just producing JSON. Similarly, Avro consumer there to verify the data... Connect AvroConverter uses the same deserializer as that

Comment: I don't have kafka-avro-console-producer, as I'm using bitnami/kafka. Is there any alternative for the approach you suggested ?

Comment: You can download those tools locally. You could also exec into the schema registry container instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've used the one in the schema registry, however its excepting key in the topic and hence getting failed there now.                                 
Error when sending message to topic testtopic with key: null, value: 24 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testtopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: Even after passing the key, it throws the error ERROR Error when sending message to topic testtopic with key: 9 bytes, value: 23 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback:52)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testtopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: Finally able to send message using kafka-avro-console-producer. However in Kafka connect, I'm getting the below error                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 1
2023-08-14 11:14:06     at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaForDeserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:428)
2

Comment: The key isn't a requirement; it's simply saying the topic doesn't exist (you should create it first using `kafka-topics --create`). I assume Kafka Connect is running in its own container, separate from the Registry? If so, then `localhost:8081` is not the correct address for that. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/  Otherwise, if you have existing data in the topic from previous attempts, that are not Avro serialized, then that data will also fail

Comment: yes, after replaced the localhost with the IP, it started working fine. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: You should not use IP's either between two containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments...

Use `kafka-avro-console-producer` or similar tooling to actually produce Avro. As written in the question, you've only produced JSON strings. This cannot work with `AvroConverter`. You could use `JSONConverter` instead, but then you need to modify the data you've produced to include a `schema` as part of the record.